# robot_state_publisher tf fail

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

map -> odom odom -> base_link succeeds in passing tf.

However, it fails to pass from base_footprint to base_link.

For example, when I check the tf tree: Broadcaster: / robot_state_publisher Average rate: 10000.0 Buffer lenth: 0.0 Most recent transform: 0.0 Oldest transform: 0.0

I wonder why I can not receive the data.

--- URDF File ---

```
<robot name = "robot">

    <link name = "base_footprint" />

    <parent link = "base_footprint" />
    <child link = "base_link" />
    <origin xyz = "0.0 0.0 0.010" rpy = "0 0 0" />
    <parent name = "base_joint" / joint>

    <link name = "base_link">
        <visual> 
            <geometry>
                <box size = "0.5 .26 .04" /> 
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy = "0 0 0" xyz = "0 0 0.075" material name = "body">
                <color rgba = "1.0 0.423529411765 0.0392156862745 1.0" />
                </material>
        </visual>
    </link>

    <link name="wheel_left1">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="0.04" radius="0.065"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="1.57 0 0" xyz="0.20 0.14 0.065"/>
            <material name="wheel">
                <color rgba="0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0"/>
            </material>
        </visual>
    </link>

    <link name="wheel_right1">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="0.04" radius="0.065" />
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="1.57 0 0" xyz="0.20 -0.14 0.065" />
            <material name="wheel">
                <color rgba="0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0" />
            </material>
        </visual>
    </link>

    <link name="wheel_left2">
        <parent link="base_link" />
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="0.04" radius="0.065" />
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="1.57 0 0" xyz="-0.20 0.14 0.065" />
            <material name="wheel">
                <color rgba="0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0" />
            </material>
        </visual>
    </link>
    <link name="wheel_right2">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="0.04" radius="0.065" />
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="1.57 0 0" xyz="-0.20 -0.14 0.065" />
            <material name="wheel">
                <color rgba="0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0" />
            </material>
        </visual>
    </link>

    <link name="base_scan">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="0.08" radius="0.05" />
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.20 0 0.10" />
            <material name="laser">
                <color rgba="0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0" />
            </material>
        </visual>
        <sensor name="base_scan" update_rate="20">
            <parent link="base_link" />
            <origin xyz="0.2 0 0.5165" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <ray>
                <horizontal samples="100" resolution="1" min_angle="-1.5708" max_angle="1.5708" />
                <vertical samples="1" resolution="1" min_angle="0" max_angle="0" />
            </ray>
        </sensor>
    </link>


    <joint name="joint1" type="fixed">
        <parent link="base_link" />
        <child link="wheel_left1" />
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" />
    </joint>

    <joint name="joint2" type="fixed">
        <parent link="base_link" />
        <child link="wheel_right1" />
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" />
    </joint>

    <joint name="joint3" type="fixed">
        <parent link="base_link" />
        <child link="wheel_left2" />
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" />
    </joint>

    <joint name="joint4" type="fixed">
        <parent link="base_link" />
        <child link="wheel_right2" />
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" />
    </joint>

    <joint name="joint5" type="fixed">
        <parent link="base_link" />
        <child link="base_scan" />
    </joint>
</robot>
```

rviz related files

```
<launch>
    <arg name="model" default="$(find dynamixel_workbench_operators)/urdf/robot.urdf" />
    <arg name="gui" default="False" />
    <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(arg model)" />
    <param name="use_gui" value="$(arg gui)" />
    <node pkg="dynamixel_workbench_operators" type="wheel_test" name="wheel_test"/>
    <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher"/>
    <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher" output="screen">
        <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="50.0" />
    </node>
    <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" />
</launch>
```

I need your help. Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320006/robot_state_publisher-tf-fail./) by [jdj](https://answers.ros.org/users/40677/jdj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2019-03-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-04-01**:
Can you please translate your question to English? As this is an English-language site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are a few issues with your URDF file which is why I'm writing an answer instead of a comment.

Line 8:

```
<parent name = "base_joint" / joint>
```

should it be

```
<parent name = "base_joint" />
```

Line 15:

```
<origin rpy = "0 0 0" xyz = "0 0 0.075" material name = "body">
```

should it be

```
<origin rpy = "0 0 0" xyz = "0 0 0.075"/>
<material name = "body">
```

I'm not sure how you didn't get any error with these errors in your URDF file because they make it an invalid XML file. Try fixing these errors and see what happens. Note that I only ran your file through an [XML beautifier](http://xmlbeautifier.com/) to make it easier to read and these errors showed up.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2019-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0